# >> operator on ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

wondering what the mistake is..

> c:lab1a.cpp(16): error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ifstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
#include "StdAfx.h"  // precompiled
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// No checking of end of stream etc.
void getw(string& t, ifstream& in)
{
  in >> t;
}
```

Comment: You've included tons of extra headers for what you've shown, but not one you're using.

Comment: Compiles without a peep here.  @chris has a point, though.  `<string>` is missing.

Comment: >> has to be overloaded !

Comment: @KaustavRay: why should it be overloaded?

Comment: @user1920482 : It has to have an overload involving both `ifstream` and `string`.  The unoverloaded `>>` only knows how to shift integer types...

Comment: @JoeZ: hasn't it already had that operation provided by **std::string**?

Comment: @user1920482 : That overload would be provided if the original poster had included `<string>`.  But they did not...

Comment: @JoeZ: I think what the OP want is to read a string from input stream. So he forgot to **#include <string>**. But, technically, you're right.

Comment: Thanks Joe Z. Not having included <string> was the problem. On hindsight, the error message makes sense.

Comment: @user1920482 : I was merely trying to explain @KaustavRay's comment.  @chris and I had already pointed out the missing `<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

The key error with this code is that it is missing the `<string>` header.

Other than that the interface is inherently broken as it doesn't support checking for errors (I realize that the stream's state can still be checked but returning the stream's state makes it much more likely that it is checked). Also, a function like that should be implemented in terns of `std::istream` rather than `std::ifstream` as it doesn't use any specifics of `std::ifstrean`.